# How to trigger firebase http function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to trigger an another function in Firebase Cloud function with javascript. But i always getting an error of  `Can't set headers after they are sent.` Please take a look at my code below:                            ................. ................. ............ ................ ................. ............... ....................... .................. ..............

```
exports.productIndexShuffleOne = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const interval = req.query.interval;
    console.log("interval: "+interval);

    const productRef = admin.firestore().collection("Products");
    const adminRef = admin.firestore().collection("Admin").doc("totalProd").get();
    const dateRef = admin.firestore().collection("Admin").doc("totalProd").collection("indexShuffle").doc("productShuffle").get();

    return dateRef.then(documentSnapshot => {
        const setDate = documentSnapshot.get('date').seconds;

        var nextDay = setDate;
        console.log("Date: "+nextDay);

        const x = setInterval(function() {
            clearInterval(x);
            return Promise.all([adminRef]).then(result => {
                const totalNum = result[0].data().totalNumber;

                console.log("totalNum: "+totalNum);

                var numberList = [];
                var index = 1;
                while(index <= totalNum){
                    numberList.push(index);
                    index++;
                }

                var cidx, ridx, tmp;
                cidx = numberList.length;
                while (cidx !== 0) {
                    ridx = Math.floor(Math.random() * cidx);
                    cidx--;
                    tmp = numberList[cidx];
                    numberList[cidx] = numberList[ridx];
                    numberList[ridx] = tmp;
                }
                console.log(numberList);

                var counter = 0;
                return productRef.get().then(snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const prodID = doc.get('productID');
                    const index = doc.get('index');

                    var newIndex = numberList[counter];
                    counter++;
                    console.log("oldIndex: "+index);
                    console.log("newIndex: "+newIndex);

                    productRef.doc(prodID).update({
                        index: newIndex
                        }, {merge: true});
                    });

                    return res.redirect('https://us-central1-myfunction-123456.cloudfunctions.net/productIndexShuffleTwo?interval='+interval);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                });
            });
        }, interval);
        return res.status(203).send(interval);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't look like complete code deployed to Cloud Functions.  Also, why are you using setInterval?

Comment: please wait i will include the complete function. I want to wait 20mins before deploying the trigger of another function that's why i include interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you've sent multiple responses while the rule is that you only allowed sending one response. Please try to look at your code and optimize it in such a way that it contains only one response.

I can see you have multiple responses as below:

```
1 -> return res.redirect('https://us-central1-myfunction-123456.cloudfunctions.net/productIndexShuffleTwo?interval='+interval);

2 -> return res.status(203).send(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can have res.redirect and then res.status.send called one after another. When you writing endpoints there rule of a thumb: always send response and only do that once. Refactor your code so there no way you can make those two calls, but only one of them.

Comment: If i use res.redirect will the another function called?

Comment: You can make res.redirect and then make any other number of calls to any functions. Important part here is not make call to res.redirect, or res.send or any other method, which sending response again, as after first time you send response, you cannot send it again - it is already away. And therefore you cannot modify it, of course.